# vue two computed properties depending on each other

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Could you help me understand or say if it is possible to do "circular" computed properties in Vue,

I want to divide date range into periods of certain durations, based on two criteria

- when `end date` is provided `interval (duration)` is calculated `dateRange / period`
- when `interval(duration)` is provided then `endDate` is calculated `startDate + interval * period`

see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dascorp/ghLmnm2c)

I already try to addy second computed property for `interval` but it went into loop and crashed the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of handling this is to use a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter). Make it so that one value is a normal data value, and the other is a computed property. Then, make it so that, when the computed property is set, it'll calculate and set the data value.

For your case, you can add a setter for `endDate`, then calculate `interval` when it's set.

```
  computed: {
    endDate: {
      get() {
        return moment(this.startDate).add(this.interval * this.periods, 'days')
      },
      set(value) {
        this.interval = // whatever `endDate` would end up being from setting interval directly, calculate that value here
      }
    },
  }
```

Comment: but this is what i did see JSFiddle i want to do calculations based on both variables either endDate or interval 
OR find out it is not possible.

Comment: I looked at the fiddle and I didn't see a computed setter anywhere, like the document page I linked. I edited my answer with an example for clarity

Comment: More directly: no, circular computed values are not possible, as issues will arise from trying to implement them, as you've seen. Plus, in concept they just can't work. You'll run into the chicken/egg problem, where one of the values has to be calculated first, but it'll depend on the other, and so on.

Comment: It looks it made a trick i updated JSFiddle to reflect the change. Thank you, i also noticed browser hangs up if i do bigger dates so it seems script to be heavy lifting somewhere

Comment: it crashes when i change startDate :( have no idea why

Comment: If it's a different issue, best bring it to another question.